# Determining the number of different ways a partition can occur?

Tags: combinatorics, integer-partitions

Say for instance a food stall keeps a record of how many complaints it receives during its 4 day work week. Complaints are classified as Mon, Tues, Wed or Thurs, depending on the day during the week which the complaint was received.
How many different classifications of 10 complaints can there be in one work week?

**My working:**
By adding the total partitions of each possible parts:
Partitions of 10 into 4 parts: $$= 9$$
Partitions of 10 into 3 parts x 2 (as there are 2 possible locations where this could start if considering consecutive day order):
$$ = 8 \times 2 $$
Partitions of 10 into 2 parts x 3:
$$ = 5 \times 3$$
Partition of 10 into 1 part x 4 (as 4 days of the week where all the complaints were reported):
$$ = 1 \times 4$$

Totalling:
$$9 + 16 + 15 + 4$$
$$=44$$

Is this correct? Logically it sounds correct but I'm not sure whether I am over/undercounting/even on the right track!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A really good way to do partitions is to use "stars and bars"

In this case you would use 10 stars representing complaints and 3 bars representing partition boundaries

So that `**||*****|***` represents (Mon, Tues, Wed, Thur) = $(2,0,5,3)$

Number of partitions = number of 13-character strings containing 10 stars and 3 bars.

To count these you just need to select the positions that you place the 3 bars and then you just fill the rest with stars.

so the answer is $$\binom {13}{3}=\frac{13 \times 12 \times 11}{3 \times 2 \times 1} =286 $$

Comment: How would I calculate this with a condition such as only counting the days where there was 4 or less complaints?

Comment: Are you asking to count the partitions for which no day has more than 4 complaints ?

Comment: Yes, for instance say i was to disregard any days where there was 5 or more complaints/only count the classifications of complaints which are less than 4

Comment: I'm still not getting what you want - We are counting partitions, what you do mean by "disregarding any days ..." - we just need to know whether or not a partition should be included in the count. Perhaps you should post a new question on which you make the extra condition clear by giving examples.